# How do I add a user and group using Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm getting an error when I try to create a user and add them to a group:

```
inherit extrausers

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " groupadd radio; \
                       useradd  -g radio -p '' elton;"
```

I've also tried variations using `usermod` with similar results. The error log  states:

```
NOTE: Executing set_user_group ...
DEBUG: Executing shell function set_user_group
NOTE: petalinux-user-image: Performing usermod with [-R /home/kenny/Desktop/radio/build/tmp/work/plnx_zynq7-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/petalinux-user-image/1.0-r0/rootfs -P root]
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                the user from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -P, --clear-password PASSWORD use clear password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -A, --prefix PREFIX_DIR       prefix directory where are located the /etc/* files
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -v, --add-subuids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate uids
  -V, --del-subuids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate uids
  -w, --add-subgids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate gids
  -W, --del-subgids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate gids

ERROR: petalinux-user-image: usermod command did not succeed.
```

I'm using Petalinux 2019.1 which is using Yocto/Thud.

Comment: Could you paste your complete recipe? It'd be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS_append = " ..."` as some other recipes can populate it?

Comment: @danlor With the exception of the header with things like SUMMARY defined this is my entire recipe.

Comment: @Kenny, and how is your recipe named? Check out the `petalinux-user-image` recipe, it seems to be the real flaw source.

Comment: When I add user with this command, I use a "+=" symbol (same as @Nayfe with "_append") and I did not get any error.
`EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += "usermod -P 'foo' bar`